# Getting "Please add error message" while validating form element in angular schema form

Tags: angularjs, jsonschema, angular-schema-form, tv4

I'm currently using angular-schema-form (https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) to generate forms based on json schema. The form generates as expected but while validating it gives me an error "Please add error message for tv4-xxx" along with the actual validation message.

Note: My work code uses UI-Bootstrap instead of Bootstrap if that matters.

Things that I've tried:

1. Created a local code and imported all of it's required dependencies and ran the application. I'm able to successfully validate the form fields with the appropriate error message and I do not get "Please add error message for tv4-xxx" error message.
2. My work code uses bower to add all of it's dependencies and as far as I'm aware it has added all of the required dependencies in the code but it still gives this error.

Screenshot of the error:

[Validation error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ5AT.jpg)

Expected is the actual validation error but it returns the message "Please add error message for tv4-xxx" along with the actual validation error which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that our angular app was validating twice, once by angular-auto-validate library and TV4.js which is used internally by angular-schema-form.

The error codes sent out by angular-schema-form were not recognized by angular-auto-validate and hence was getting "Please add error message for tv4-xxx".

Disabling the validation solved the problem.